# Mac Resolving Ubuntu Hostname on Windows Network

Tags: macos, ubuntu, networking, mac, samba

I have a wired network using the workgroup of `PAPERTECH` with the following machines:

- Windows XP (hostname: `WinXP`)
- Ubuntu 12.10 (hostname: `WebServer`) - via Samba
- Mac OS X 10.9 (hostname: `MacMini`)

The problem is that the Mac cannot resolve the hostname for the Ubuntu web server as it cannot ping it.

#### Ping Summary:

- From the Windows machine I **can** ping `MacMini` **and** `WebServer`.
- From the Ubuntu machine I **can** ping `WinXP.PAPERTECH.local` but **cannot** ping `MacMini.PAPERTECH.local`.
- From the Mac machine I **can** ping `WinXP.PAPERTECH.local` but **cannot** ping `WebServer.PAPERTECH.local`.

#### Mac Setup

I've set the workgroup using the Network settings under: *System Preferences > Network > Ethernet (Advanced ...) > WINS*. I've also enabled 'Share files and folders using SMB' under: *System Preferences > Sharing > File Sharing*.

Despite the above settings the Mac is still unable to ping or connect to the server using the hostname: `WebServer` (NOTE: it is able to ping the IP address it resolves to).

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to add the line

```
 netbios name = your_pc_name
```

in the file */etc/samba/smb.conf*, and to restart the services *nmbd* and *smbd* and/or to  reboot?

Comment: I tried adding this below `[global]` settings and restarted both *nmbd* and *smbd* but it didn't seem to make a difference. 

I then also tried a reboot after making the changes but it didn't seem to make a difference either.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping by IP, then the issue is a DNS resolution issue.

There are two ways to resolve your issue if you want to use names.

Set up a DNS server to be used by all your machines.

Update your hosts files on the Linux and Mac boxes.  This is located in **/etc/hosts**

Comment: The hostname's mentioned above are the FQDN's on the network so I would have thought that I don't need to edit the `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: FQDN or not, if you cannot resolve a name to an IP you will not be able to connect. Did you try @MariusMatutiae s answer?

Comment: Yep, tried @MariusMatutiae's suggestion but it didn't appear to make a difference.

I guess I'm expecting that I should be able to resolve the FQDN on both Windows and Mac as they are both part of the same network and workgroup.

Comment: For FQDN to work you need to have a DNS server set up as I specified.  Or you have to configure your DHCP server to provide the full DNS info.